# Incomplete KBibTex Installation

Tags: 12.04, latex

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and I tried to install KBibTex with the Software-Center.

After the installation I get the following Popup:

[image]

If I press okay then the program starts as usual. But as soon as I press the 'open' button it crashes:

[image]

I reinstalled it, but I still get the same error message. How can I fix it?

Comment: You are trying to install a KDE programme on Unity. I believe that in this particular case it should not work.